# Batch script to hide folders with a specific string

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, directory

I'm looking to create a batch script for folders starting with the word GFI (followed by an individual name each time) to be recursively set to hidden on a regular basis (I imagine I would have to run the script through windows task scheduler to achieve the second part.) Any help would be of great assistance as I have no idea where to start in the slightest!

Thanks in advance,
Kieren Perry

Answer (score 0):

***HideFolders.bat***:

```
@Echo OFF

For /D /R "C:\Folder\" %%# in ("GFI*%~1") DO (ATTRIB +H "%%#")

Pause&Exit
```

Usage:

```
HideFolders.bat "IndividualName"
```

For Example if you launch:

```
HideFolders.bat "Test"
```

...Searchs folders by this pattern:

```
GFI*Test
```

Answer (score 0):

This code hides all GFI folders, no matter of search patterns:

```
for /r /d "\" %%i in (GFI*) do attrib +h "%%~fi"
```